# How to change siblings class with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
     <li class="span3">
         <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                     <a href="#" class="tip SetPrimaryImage" > <i class="icon-star-   empty"></i></a>
         </div>

    </li>

     <li class="span3">
         <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                     <a href="#" class="tip SetPrimaryImage" > <i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
         </div>

    </li>

    <li class="span3">
         <div class="thumbnail text-center">
                     <a href="#" class="tip SetPrimaryImage" > <i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
         </div>

    </li>
```

I would like to change icon class of siblings if they have class icon-star.

So whichever I click it should change the other siblings icon to icon-star-empty if they have the class icon-star?

I cannot do it with the following :

```
$('this).siblings().find('i').removeClass('icon-star').addClass('icon-star-empty');
```

Comment: What is `this` referring to?

Comment: Fix your code, loads of mistakes. Is it the mistakes or it not working?

Comment: sorry that refers to link <a> I found a way to fix it by $('ul li').find('i').removeClass('star').addClass('emptystart'); then I set the $(this). addClass('star');

Comment: The problem is that the `a` elements don't have any siblings. You want to find the siblings of `this`'s parent's (`div`) parents (`li`). You need to traverse up the DOM before looking for the siblings.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are refering `this` to anchor elements.based on that,you can use:

```
$(this).closest('li').siblings().find('i').removeClass('icon-star').addClass('icon-star-empty');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pt9bh/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

May be the below code will help you.

```
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('.thumbnails').find('i').removeClass('icon-star').addClass('icon-star-empty');    
        $(this).find('i').addClass('icon-star');

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that you're changing the class on the click on itself. That is what `this` would do. You need to check for the siblings instead of the current element.

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().find('here-find-the-children').attr('icon-star-empty');
```

And after the change, keep the same class for the current li element as:

```
$(this).attr('class', 'the-class-that-was');
```

Here is a complete example:

```
$('li').click(function () { /* click */
   var parentEl = $(this).parent(); /* ul */
   var childElparentEl.find('li'); /* all the li elements */
   childEl.attr('class', 'icon-star-empty'); /* class for all */
   $(this).attr('class', 'icon-star'); /* change the class for the current */
}
```

This would do the trick!